# Серьезный вопрос о работе с sqlalchemy

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlalchemy

Подскажите пожалуйста, начал изучать sqlalchemy, и возник следующий вопрос.
На сколько я понял, обязательно нужно объявлять класс со всеми столбами таблицы, что бы с ней взаимодействовать. А что если в уже существующем проекте уже бд с десятками таблиц с десятками, если не сотнями, столбцов, и не внедрена sqlalchemy то, что бы работать с такой бд нужно создавать на каждую таблицу свой класс и описывать каждую таблицу? На сколько я понял по видео-гайдам, раньше был способ взайимодействовать с таблицами без объявления классов, через autoload, сейчас его убрали?
Можете поподробнее пожалуйста рассказть на эту тему пожалуйста, тех. документация на сайте конечно довольно обширная, но читать все равно мне пока что больно такое. И еще чем отличаются эти 3 способа определения столбцов:

- `user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)`
- `user_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)`
- `user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)`

Был бы очень благодарен обширному ответу.